# Bootstrap modal form submit not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

please i need someone to help me check if i'm missing something. The form in the Bootstrap modal wont submit.

my HTML codes for the modal (sidebar.php)

```
<!-- start Joel's modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">E-Logbook Entry</h4>
        </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <form id="modal-form" method="post" action="notes_functions.php">
       <fieldset>      
      <label>Log Entry</label>
            <textarea rows="4" cols="50" class="form-control" name="note_content" placeholder="What have you learnt today?..."></textarea>
    </form>
</div>
<div class = "modal-footer">
        <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default" data-dismiss = "modal">
           Close
        </button>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="submitnote" value="Submit" />
     </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- end Joel's modal -->
```

codes for the PHP file (notes_functions.php)

```
<?php
include_once 'database-config.php';

if (isset($_POST['submitnote'])) {

    $noteContent = strip_tags($_POST['note_content']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO account_notes (note_contents) VALUES ('$noteContent')";
    $dbh->exec($sql);
    echo "New record created successfully";
    echo "Log details = ".$note_contents;
 }
?>
```

my AJAX codes for submitting the form

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var frm = $('#modal-form');
frm.submit(function (ev) {
    $.ajax({
        type: frm.attr('method'),
        url: frm.attr('action'),
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: frm.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            alert('ok');
        }
    });

    ev.preventDefault();
 });
</script>
```

I can't seem to spot the error :-(

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {` instead of `if (isset($_POST['submitnote'])) {` because `name` attribute of form submit button is `submit` not `submitnote`. `name` attributes are going through `POST` not the `id`. So check and correct for each one

Comment: I have made the changes, but still no effect. BTW, the modal is triggered by clicking on a date from a calendar script. The idea is, when a date is clicked, the modal is called, then a user can fill the form in the modal and submit to MySQL database.    `<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.responsive-calendar').responsiveCalendar({
           onDayClick: function(events) { $("#myModal").modal();}

        });
      });
    </script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:-

1.Instead of `if (isset($_POST['submitnote'])) {` use `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {`

2.Put `ev.preventDefault();` before  `$.ajax({`

Comment: I have made these corrections but it still isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

your submit button is not in the form. place it in the form or add this to the button

```
form="modal-form"
```

like so:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="submitnote" value="Submit" form="modal-form" />
```